# How Match Regular expression of international number in android

Tags: android, regex

i have a EditText in my activity where i take a phone number from user.. Now user provides a number activity and based on xml rules you i have to tell whether application routes the phone number or not.

Comment: i have a EditText in my activity where i take a phone number from user.. Now user provides a number in activity and based on xml rules you i have to tell whether my application should route the phone number or not.

Comment: You nkow you could edit your initial question right?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a java question, you need to know how to build regular expressions. So I assume you know how to fetch the value of the edit text. Lets assume you have loaded the phone number in a `String phoneNumber`. So now how do you check against a regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

....
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\+0[8-9][0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  // The phone number matches the template given. do the routing.
}
```

In th eexample I have given I am searching for phone numbers that start with + (note that `+` is a special character for regexes, thus I need to escape it, the same holds for `$`, `.`, `^`), then I expect a zero, 8 or 9, then exactly 2 digits, a dash 2 more digits and 3 more digits. The if `matcher.matches()` will return true only if the `phoneNumber` is exactly of the described format. Hopefully this will give you a brief introduction to the regex power of java.

Answer (score 0):

[ITU: National Numbering Plans](http://www.itu.int/oth/T0202.aspx?parent=T0202) can help you with the harder problem.

Your question is poor enough that any one of my link, Boris's regex-centric answer, or an answer that focused on nothing more than Android's GUI could be what you're really looking for. Please keep this in mind for future questions.